# Search multiple values specified by equal symbol within string (VBA)

Tags: string, vba, function, search

Let's say I have a string str_content with the following content (yes, with break lines because I'm reading a file):

```
str_content = "PRODUCT label = 'Equipment XS'
equipment size = 9.75 wt = 0.5 quality = 0.001969
rent dist = 0 index = 40.774278 tp = 48
rent dist = 50 index = 0 tp = 48
rent dist = 130 index = 0 tp = 60"
```

How would be a function in VBA to obtain whenever value I want just by using this?

```
extract_data(str_content, "PRODUCT label") = Equipment XS
extract_data(str_content, "wt") = 0.5
extract_data(str_content, "quality") = 0.001969
```

More than this, going through the "rent" section like this:

```
extract_data(str_content, rent(0), “index”) = 40.774278
extract_data(str_content, rent(0), “tp”) = 48
extract_data(str_content, rent(0), “dist”) = 0
extract_data(str_content, rent(1), “index”) = 0
extract_data(str_content, rent(1), “tp”) = 48
extract_data(str_content, rent(1), “dist”) = 50
extract_data(str_content, rent(2), “index”) = 0
extract_data(str_content, rent(2), “tp”) = 60
extract_data(str_content, rent(2), “dist”) = 130
```

Does any expert know this? I'm not an IT guy, so this will help a lot some work I have in Excel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a lot of people here ready to help you with your code, but this is not a code writing service. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sData As String
    Dim oData As Object

    ' Read data from file
    sData = ReadTextFile(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\sample.txt", -1)
    ' Parse text data to structured nested dictionaries
    Set oData = ParseData(sData)
    ' Test
    Debug.Print oData("PRODUCT")(0)("label")
    Debug.Print oData("equipment")(0)("size")
    Debug.Print oData("equipment")(0)("wt")
    Debug.Print oData("equipment")(0)("quality")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(0)("dist")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(0)("index")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(0)("tp")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(1)("dist")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(1)("index")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(1)("tp")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(2)("dist")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(2)("index")
    Debug.Print oData("rent")(2)("tp")

End Sub

Function ParseData(sContent As String) As Object

    Dim spN As String
    Dim spQ As String
    Dim sDelim As String
    Dim aSections
    Dim oSections As Object
    Dim aSection
    Dim aParams
    Dim oSection As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sParam
    Dim aValues
    Dim v

    spN = "[+-]?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?" ' pattern for number
    spQ = "'[^']*'|""(?:\\""|[^""])*""" ' pattern for quoted string
    sDelim = Mid(1 / 2, 2, 1) ' regional decimal delimiter
    ' Extract each section
    ParseResponse "^([\w ]*?)((?: \w* ?\= ?(?:" & spN & "|" & spQ & "))+)$", sContent, aSections, False
    ' aSections - sections array
    ' Create dictionary for sections
    Set oSections = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Process each section
    For Each aSection In aSections
        ' aSection - section array
        ' aSection(0) - section name
        ' aSection(1) - section content
        ' Extract each parameter
        ParseResponse "(\w* ?\= ?(?:" & spN & "|" & spQ & "))", aSection(1), aParams, False
        ' aParams - parameters array
        ' Create dictionary for current section entries if not exists
        If Not oSections.Exists(aSection(0)) Then Set oSections(aSection(0)) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Current section entries
        Set oSection = oSections(aSection(0))
        ' Current section entry index
        i = oSection.Count
        ' Create new section entry and dictionary for parameters
        Set oSection(i) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Process each parameter
        For Each sParam In aParams
            ' sParam - parameter string
            ' Extract values
            ParseResponse "(\w*) ?\= ?(?:(" & spN & ")|(" & spQ & "))", sParam, aValues, False, False
            ' aValues - name and value array
            ' aValues(0) - parameter name
            ' aValues(1) - parameter numeric value
            ' aValues(2) - parameter string value
            ' Evaluating value as number or string
            If IsEmpty(aValues(2)) Then ' Number
                v = CDbl(Replace(aValues(1), ".", sDelim))
            Else ' Quoted string
                v = Mid(aValues(2), 2, Len(aValues(2)) - 2)
            End If
            ' Assign value to section entry parameter name
            oSection(i)(aValues(0)) = v
        Next
    Next
    Set ParseData = oSections

End Function

Sub ParseResponse(sPattern, sResponse, aData, Optional bAppend As Boolean = True, Optional bNestSubMatches = True, Optional bGlobal = True, Optional bMultiLine = True, Optional bIgnoreCase = True)

    Dim oMatch
    Dim aTmp0()
    Dim sSubMatch

    If Not (IsArray(aData) And bAppend) Then aData = Array()
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = bGlobal
        .MultiLine = bMultiLine
        .IgnoreCase = bIgnoreCase
        .Pattern = sPattern
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sResponse)
            If oMatch.SubMatches.Count = 1 Then
                PushItem aData, oMatch.SubMatches(0)
            Else
                If bNestSubMatches Then
                    aTmp0 = Array()
                    For Each sSubMatch In oMatch.SubMatches
                        PushItem aTmp0, sSubMatch
                    Next
                    PushItem aData, aTmp0
                Else
                    For Each sSubMatch In oMatch.SubMatches
                        PushItem aData, sSubMatch
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub PushItem(aData, vItem, Optional bAppend As Boolean = True)

    If Not (IsArray(aData) And bAppend) Then aData = Array()
    ReDim Preserve aData(UBound(aData) + 1)
    aData(UBound(aData)) = vItem

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath As String, lFormat As Long) As String

    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With

End Function
```

For testing I saved the file `sample.txt` as Unicode on the desktop with the content:

```
PRODUCT label = 'Equipment XS'
equipment size = 9.75 wt = 0.5 quality = 0.001969
rent dist = 0 index = 40.774278 tp = 48
rent dist = 50 index = 0 tp = 48
rent dist = 130 index = 0 tp = 60
```

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi @RichardFreinz
Thank you so much, the code worked very well, it was what I was looking for.